# React slick slider not working properly after fetching multiple images parallely using map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, slider, react-slick

I implemented react slick slider and I am getting the images by applying map on array of imageArray data. From the key I get , I have to call url as image src to get the image. I am getting images but the carousel is not obeying rules defined in settings due to dynamic fetching of images.

```
import Slider from "react-slick";
```

...

```
 let settings = {
    accessibility: false,
    slidesToShow: 4.25,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    rows: 2,
    lazyLoad: true,
    dots: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    infinite: false,
}
```

...

```
<Slider {...settings}>
  {imageArray.map(individualImage => {
    if (individualImage.DESCRIPTION.toLowerCase().includes(selectedDescription.toLowerCase())) {
      return <img title={individualImage.DESCRIPTION} alt={individualImage.DESCRIPTION + ' image'} className={individualImage.KEY === imageSelected ? borderColor : 'image-default-border'} onClick={() => imgClick(field, individualImage.KEY, individualImage.DESCRIPTION)} src={`www/url.com/key=${individualImage.KEY}`} />
    }
    return true
  })}
  {imageArray.map(individualImage => {
    if (individualImage.DESCRIPTION1.toLowerCase().includes(selectedDescription?.toLowerCase())) {
      return <img title={individualImage.DESCRIPTION1} alt={individualImage.DESCRIPTION1 + ' image'} className={individualImage.KEY1 === imageSelected ? borderColor : 'image-default-border'} onClick={() => imgClick(field, individualImage.KEY1, individualImage.DESCRIPTION1)} src={`www/url.com/key=${individualImage.KEY1}`} />
    }
    return true
  })}

</Slider>
```